# Dynamic menu configuration section with conditional inputs on Magento custom module

Tags: magento, serialization, backend, depends

I've followed [this tutorial](http://www.itera-research.com/de/magento-custom-menu-configuration-section-using-a-field-array/) to create a custom dynamic backend configuration with serialized data, and everything is working as expected. yay

But now I want to take another step and only show some inputs when a specific value is selected in a select box. [I know that I can use](http://alanstorm.com/magento_system_configuration_in_depth_tutorial/)  when doing this with `system.xml`, but how can I accomplish the same thing via code with dynamics serialized tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing some kind of Javascript workaround to enable/disable a certain input.

```
function togleSelect(element)
{
    var val = element.value;
    var name = element.name;
    if (val == 0) // select value to be triggered
    {
        name = name.substr(0, name.lastIndexOf("[")) + "[name_of_my_input]";
        var target = document.getElementsByName(name);
        target[0].disabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        name = name.substr(0, name.lastIndexOf("[")) + "[name_of_my_input]";
        var target = document.getElementsByName(name);
        target[0].disabled = true;
    }
}
```

It's not the best solution but it's working.